# Transpose text using sed

Tags: sed, text-manipulation, transpose

Please help me figure out how to solve this using `sed`.

Given the following text:

```
Kerala
        4222        8129        8163        8164        

Delhi      
        8502        8503        8504        8505       
Goa
        1          39      45
```

I want to convert it to the following format:

```
Kerala,4222
Kerala,8129
Kerala,8163
Delhi,8502
Delhi,8503
Delhi,8504
Delhi,8505
Goa,1
Goa,39
Goa,45
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed` and not `awk`(or `perl`, `python` etc)?

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! You should know that questions here are generally expected to show research effort, which is probably why it's currently being downvoted. SU is not a script writing service; if you show some steps you've taken, we can help you iterate on them. Make sure to read the [help center](http://superuser.com/help/asking) to get a feel for what's expected here.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume, that your file has the name `test1`

The whole command then looks like this (in one line):

```
names=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/[a-zA-Z]/p" | sed "s/$/;/g") && names2=(${names//;/ }) && for var in "${names2[@]}"; do numbers=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/$var/{n;p}" | sed "s/\s/;/g"); numbers2=(${numbers//;/ }); for num in "${numbers2[@]}"; do echo "$var,$num"; done; done
```

For a better view, look at this script:

```
names=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/[a-zA-Z]/p" | sed "s/$/;/g") 
names2=(${names//;/ })
for var in "${names2[@]}"; do 
    numbers=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/$var/{n;p}" | sed "s/\s/;/g")
    numbers2=(${numbers//;/ })
    for num in "${numbers2[@]}"; do 
        echo "$var,$num"
    done
done
```

Now I want to describe all parts of the command

**DESCRIPTION OF THE COMMAND**

The command `names=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/[a-zA-Z]/p" | sed "s/$/;/g")` gives me a list of the names separated with a semicolon, in your case `Kerala;Delhi;Goa`. I want them in this form, because now I can change them into an array with the second command `names2=(${names//;/ })`. Now I iterate through all the names, which is done with the first `for` loop.

The command `numbers=$(cat test1 | sed -n "/$var/{n;p}" |sed "s/\s/;/g");` gives me the numbers for the current variable `$var`. I.e. for `Kerala` this would be `4222;8129;8163;8164`. The behaviour is the same like in the first command: I want to change them into an array, so I can iterate through them, which is done with the next command `numbers2=(${numbers//;/ });`. Now I iterate through the numbers and print them onto the screen

```
for num in "${numbers2[@]}"; do echo "$var,$num"; done
```

I hope this is understandable.

Comment: It works...Thank you very much for your timely reply...